# When estimating worst-case execution time T(x,y) of an algorithm, should I count if statements?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

When estimating worst-case execution time T(x,y) of an algorithm, should I count if statements?

```
def foobar(x,y):
    result = 0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            if self.checkSomething(x, y):
                result = result + 1
    return result
```

So I have 1+x*y when counting assignment statements.

I recognise that e.g. T(n) is not the same as O(n).

Comment: It depends on what you want to count. There is no universal convention on which operations should be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to count the time it takes to calculate the condition `self.checkSomething(x,y)`, and that is always > 0.  You'll get an operation count, but when you're doing complexity analysis, you don't really know how much time each of those operations take.

For that reason, it doesn't matter whether you count the evaluation of the `if`or not. `some_unknown_time` is the same as `some_unknown_time + some_other_unknown_time`, since you're never going to know that those times actually are.

You can simplify the whole `T(x,y)` equation along the same lines, because again you don't really know the time cost of each operation represented, and you never will.   So, you can change all constant terms and constant factors in non-recursive terms to 1 without changing any practical results.  So, for instance `T(x,y) = 5x + 3y + 7` is equivalent to `T(x, y) = x + y + 1`.  BUT `T(n) = T(n-1) + 1` is NOT the same as `T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + 1`